# Multiplicar numero * 2 en un input utilizando un boton

Tags: javascript, html, input

Estoy tratando de realizar un input en el cual le paso un numero y al dar click en un boton me lo multiplique por dos. Y me devuela el resultado en un parrafo por abajo del input. Trate de multiplicar counter + es valor que le paso al input por 2 pero me da como resultado que btnStart es null. No se si el problema esta en la logica de la multiplicacion o directamente en la funcion del boton.

```js
const counter = document.querySelector('#cowCounter');
const btnStart = document.querySelector('#btn');
const result = document.querySelector('#textResult');

btnStart.addEventListener("click", start);

function start(){
   counter.value * 2;
   return result = counter;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Cows</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <h1>COWS</h1>
        <h1>COWS</h1>
    </div>

    <div>
        <h2>The Other World</h2>
    </div>

    <div>
        <p>Let's start with production</p>
    </div>

    <div class="inputClass">
        <label for="cowCounter">Use only numbers from 1 to 20</label>
        <input id="cowCounter" value="0" type="text" >
        <button type="button" id="btn">GO!</button>
        <br>
        <p id="textResult"></p>
    </div>

    <div>
        <img id="cowImg" src="img/pngegg.png" alt="vaca">
    </div>
   
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Pon solo esto en la función start():  `result.innerHTML = counter.value * 2;`

Comment: Si creo que esa es la solucion para multiplicar cualquier numero por 2 pero todavia en la consola me devuelve que "btnStart is null"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Primero, yo asignaría los elementos HTML por su id con document.getElementById.
Luego, el valor de un input obtenido mediante `.value` es de tipo texto, así que hay que convertirlo a un entero (mediante `parseInt`)
Y como `result` es un `<p>` deberías mostrar el resultado en el `innerHTML` de ese `<p>` (es decir, lo que hay dentro de  `<p>` y `</p>`)

```
var counter = document.getElementById('cowCounter');
var btnStart = document.getElementById('btn');
var result = document.getElementById('textResult');

btnStart.addEventListener("click", start);

function start(){
   result.innerHTML = parseInt(counter.value) * 2
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, entendi perfecto lo que me dijiste... tambien el problema era que main.js lo tenia mal insertado en html. era cuestion de revisar todo y se soluciono cambiando de lugar el <script>

Comment: Si el script hace uso de elementos del DOM que no están cargados, obtendrá resultados null. Una forma de asegurarse de que todo el HTML está cargado antes de usar Javascript es meter tu script al final del <body> Incluso, puedes hacer un <body onload='inicio()'> y la función inicio() se ejecutará cuando todo el <body> esté cargado.

Comment: Claro, lo cambie al final del body y anduvo perfecto. Muchas gracias por tiempo! Saludos.